# I am trying to remove the "0:00:00". How can I do this?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

```py
from datetime import date
import random

earlier_date = date(2017, 6, random.randint(1, 25))
later_date = date(2017, 6, random.randint(earlier_date.day + 1, 28))

days_between = later_date - earlier_date

print("There are", days_between, "days between", earlier_date, "and", later_date)
```

I am trying to remove the "0:00:00". How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can just call the days attribute for the timedelta object

```py
# datetime.timdelta object
days_between.days

# datetime.date object
later_date.day, earlier_date.day
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import date
import random
earlier_date = date(2017, 6, random.randint(1, 25))
later_date = date(2017, 6, random.randint(earlier_date.day + 1, 28))


days_between = later_date - earlier_date

print(earlier_date)
print(later_date)

print("There are", days_between.days, "days between", earlier_date, "and", later_date)
```

> 2017-06-12
>
> 2017-06-14

> There are 2 days between 2017-06-12 and 2017-06-14